# JOIN in Symfony Doctrine with QueryBuilder between 2 entities

Tags: php, symfony, join, orm, doctrine

I am relatively new to Doctrine and am having an absolute nightmare trying to get a join between two entities returned correctly. I don't really understand the DRM that Doctrine uses as much as I would like at the moment so it really is just a case of trial and error at the moment.

I have two entities, one is document and one is document-sow-detail. I need to join the two where the document_id exists in the document-dow-detail table/entity as to get a couple of fields that exist in the document-dow-detail entity returned.

So, within my document repository, I have attempted the following code (with not a lot of understanding of what is happening). Can someone point me as to what is happening here and why it is not working?

```
    $db = $this->createQueryBuilder($this->alias);
    $db->addSelect("dsd");
    $db->leftJoin("doc_sow_detail",'dsd','ON',"id_document");
```

When I breakpoint and evaluate the $db->getQuery() function in my IDE this is the _dql that has been generated.

```
SELECT d, dsd FROM BillingBundle\Entity\Document d LEFT JOIN doc_sow_detail dsd ON id_document
```

Can anyone give me a clue as to what I am doing wrong here before I chuck my computer out the window?
Thanks!

Comment: Learning new stuff can be frustrating.  Have you looked at the doctrine manual? http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html.  You are close.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example of doctrine join which joins product category on category:

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select('p')
    ->from('BRBProductBundle:Product', 'p')
    ->join('p.category', 'c')
    ->where('1 = 1');
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: HI, thanks for your help. The problem is, the relationship between the entities exists in the document_sow_detail table.. so currently the entity manager is getting an instance of the document and looking for a doc_sow_details relationship which doesn't exist. The document_sow_detail entity holds a relationship within it viaa variable called 'id_document' which links it to the document entity. Would this query have to be executed in the repository for the document_sow_detail?

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd post my solution.

I had to change my entity structures due to the one-way relationship between the two entities.

I moved the required entity properties onto the document entity which negated my need for a join. This is probably where these properties needed to be in the first place.